# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ConnectionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, actionmailer

I am trying to add a new Action Mailer to my app and when I navigated to connections/new I received this error message:

> Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant
>   ConnectionsController

full trace

```
    activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:478:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:552:in `get'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `constantize'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `controller_reference'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `controller'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
rollbar (2.4.0) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:24:in `block in call'
rollbar (2.4.0) lib/rollbar.rb:842:in `scoped'
rollbar (2.4.0) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
rollbar (2.4.0) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

controllers/connections_controller.rb

```
class ConnectionionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @connection = connection.new
  end

  def create
    @connection = Connection.new(connection_params)
    if @connection.save
      name = params[:connection][:your_name]
      email = params[:connection][:email]
      body = params[:connection][:mentors_name, :mentees_name]

      connectionMailer.connection_email(name, email, body).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Message sent. Someone at Jr. Dev Mentoring will respond to your message soon. Thank you."
      redirect_to new_connection_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Error occured, message has not been sent. You must complete all form fields"
      redirect_to new_connection_path
    end
  end
  private
    def connection_params
      params.require(:connection).permit(:your_name, :email, :mentors_name, :mentees_name)
    end
end
```

mailers/connection_mailer.rb

```
class ConnectionsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default to: 'info@jrdevmentoring.com'

    def connection_email(name, email, body)
        @name = name
        @email = email
        @body = body
        mail(from: email, subject: 'Jr. Dev Mentoring Connect Form Message')
    end
end
```

models/connection.rb

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :your_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

views/connections/new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <h1 class="text-center">Let's Connect</h1>
      <p class="text-center">I'd like to connect</p> 
      <div class="well">
        <%= form_for @connection do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :your_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :your_name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group, 'Mentors Name'">
            <%= f.label :comments %>
            <%= f.text_area :mentors_name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group, 'Mentees Name'">
            <%= f.label :comments %>
            <%= f.text_area :mentees_name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>

          <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

views/connection_mailer/connection_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>You have received a message from the Jr. Dev Mentoring site's connect form, from <%= "#{ @name }, #{ @email }." %></p>
    <p><%= @body %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

db/migrate

```
class CreateConnections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :connections do |t|
      t.string :your_name
      t.string :email
      t.text :mentors_name
      t.text :mentees_name

      t.timestamps
    end
```

schema

```
 create_table "connections", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "your_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "mentors_name"
    t.text     "mentees_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users,:controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }
  resources :users do
    resource :profile
  end
  resources :connections
  resources :contacts
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  namespace :mentee do
    root 'pages#home'
    get '/mentor_profiles' => 'profiles#mentor_profiles'
  end
  namespace :mentor do
    root 'pages#home'
    get '/mentee_profiles' => 'profiles#mentee_profiles'
  end
  root 'pages#home'
```

Comment: in new action replace this `@connection = connection.new` with `@connection = Connection.new` and try

Comment: @AmitSharma...I've made the change but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: comment out this line then try `connectionMailer.connection_email(name, email, body).deliver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several spelling and capitalization errors in my `connections_controller.rb` file

- replaced `class ConnectionionsController < ApplicationController` with `class ConnectionsController < ApplicationController`
- replaced `@connection = connection.new` with `@connection = Connection.new`
- replaced `connectionMailer.connection_email(name, email, body).deliver` with `ConnectionMailer.connection_email(name, email, body).deliver`